# TypeError with UpdateCursor on a Field with a Coded Text Domain

Tags: arcpy, cursor, domains

Trying to run an `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor` on a field that has a Coded Text Domain.

I keep getting a typeError.

Not sure if there's a certain syntax that I need to be using when trying to update the row or what, but Esri documentation doesn't have anything.

Here's what I've got:

```
edit = arcpy.da.Editor(workspace)
edit.startEditing(False, False)
edit.startOperation()

# Create update cursor
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    # For each row, evaluate the DateGroomed value, and update Status
    for row in cursor:
        if (row[0] != None):
            if (row[0] < datetime.datetime.now() and (row[1] == "Groomed" or row[1] == "Groomed Classic")):
                row[1] = 'Groomed Previously'
                cursor.updateRow(row)

edit.stopOperation()
edit.stopEditing(True)
```

The error flags on line 11 here (row[1] = 'Groomed Previously') with:
"TypeError: cannot update the table"
The domain value and description are both "Groomed Previously" for the value I'm trying to fill in.

Comment: It may be that row[1] does not have a string type. What is the type of the field of row[1]?

Comment: It's a string field with a text domain.

Comment: How did you solve it man??

Answer (score 0):

It may come down to the `startEditing` parameters you've passed in. The 2nd parameter for that one toggles multi-user mode on or off; it may be worth trying to change that to `True` if your workspace is an sde (see [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/editor.htm))

On the other hand, if row[1](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/editor.htm) has a string *description* but a different type of coded value, that may result in a TypeError.